# How is pandas able to import `from pandas` within the very code of pandas?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am trying to understand Python packaging better. I noticed that in a lot of projects, some of the project code seems to import from the project *itself*.

Case in point:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py

This internal `.py` file in the pandas package is importing a bunch of things from pandas?

```
...

from pandas._libs import (
    Timestamp,
    internals as libinternals,
    lib,
    writers,
)
from pandas._libs.internals import BlockPlacement
from pandas._libs.tslibs import IncompatibleFrequency
from pandas._typing import (
    ArrayLike,
    AxisInt,
    DtypeObj,
    F,
    FillnaOptions,
    IgnoreRaise,
    QuantileInterpolation,
    Shape,
    npt,
)
from pandas.errors import AbstractMethodError
from pandas.util._decorators import cache_readonly
from pandas.util._exceptions import find_stack_level
from pandas.util._validators import validate_bool_kwarg
...
```

How are they doing this? And is this good practice?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why would you expect anything else? Should a package not be allowed to use its own code and sub packages? Very hard to build anything if you would need a separate package for any code that wants to interact with each other.

Comment: Yeah, massive headache :P - This is me trying to learn how to best avoid a strictly tree-like module structure (ie. how can many parts of my code in various modules import common functionality from a few common .py files, etc...)

Comment: Obviously you must not have cyclic imports but `yourpkg.services` importing from `yourpkg.utils` and 
`yourpkg.services` importing from `yourpkg.entities` which also import from `yourpkg.utils` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The issue for me is when you have deeply nested packages, and you want to import from outside the subdirectories.

Comment: Eg `mypgk.data.caching.schema` and `mypgk.display.plotting.figures` not importing from `mypgk.utils`

Answer (score 2):

This is a common practice in Python.
The `pandas` package is a directory with a `__init__.py` file in it.
The `__init__.py` file is executed when the package is imported.
It can contain code that imports other modules in the package.
This is how the `pandas` package imports the `pandas._libs` package.

Comment: I would also add that if A imports B which import C, python allows `from B import C` (or `from A.B import C`)- ie. the imports of a module are also exported. As such, the panda's init exports all the submodules it imported

Comment: This probably answers a lot of my questions on this. Seems better than messing about with sys.path.insert or relative imports